# Youtube audio uri exception using VideoLibrary (libvideo)

Tags: c#, video-library

I have a code to extract audio url using VideoLibrary. But Video.Uri throws an exception.

> An invalid request URI was provided. The request URI must either be an absolute URI or BaseAddress must be set.

I can't understand why this happens. How can I solve this problem?

```
YouTube yt = YouTube.Default;
string link = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QNJL6nfu__Q";
foreach (var item in yt.GetAllVideos(link))
{
   if (item.AdaptiveKind == AdaptiveKind.Audio)
      Console.WriteLine(item.Uri);
}
```

Comment: Did you end up figuring out what was the issue? I'm having the exact problem, it was working for a while and now no matter what url I give it, it throws above error.

Answer (score 1):

The VideoLibrary is outdated. Use the Nefarius-VideoLibrary instead